# Filtering view results with a toggle for entity referenced fields that are 'null'

Tags: views, entities

I have 2 content types:
Content type 1: '**Country**'
Content type 2: '**Indicator**'

The Indicator content type has 3 fields
Field 1: '**Indicator Value 1**' (a number)
Field 1: '**Indicator Value 2**' (a number)
Field 2: '**Country**' Entity Reference for the country

I have a view that displays a list of countries and has the entity reference relationship setup to display referenced fields that are from the indicator content type.

My issue is that not all countries have both indicator values available (some only 'Indicator Value 1', some only 'Indicator Value 2', some both, and some neither). I want to have 2 range filters in the view, one for each Indicator. I am using a slider widget where I need to indicate minimum and maximum.

As soon as I add a range filter, because of the minimum and maximum any countries that don't contain both indicators within the range are removed from the results.

I want to be able to see all results by default, including the ones with null values. And have the option to search by one or both indicators using the slider filter.